# SQL: Insert into Ignore if Exist

Tags: sql

I want to `insert from Table1 the rows are not in Table2.`

The thing is a mistake to have the Node with `parentId = 0` on the Table2.

So I need to get all the sons from all parent are in Table2 and `insert` them if they are not on Table2 with the Key the parent used to have on Table2.

I have for each table two keys, not just one. There is my problem.

Plz if someone can give me hand. I could use `cursors`.

```
Table1
IDNode, IDParent
1       0
2       1
3       1
4       1
5       0
6       5


Table2
IDNode, IDKey
1       1
1       7
2       6
4       2
5       3





IdNode  IDparent IDkey
2       1           1
3       1           1
4       1           1
2       1           7
3       1           7
4       1           7
remove the IDNode2 with IDKey6
remove the IDNode4 with IDKey2
6       5           4
```

The key of the father is more important, if in my Table2 I have a parent with a key, I need to find form table1 the sons, insert them with the key of father, if exist the son with different key delete it, after all delete  the parent node from table2

Comment: hi..i think the result for table-2 which you are showing here is confusing..please make it clear..

Comment: "insert them if they are not on Table2 with the Key the parent used to have on Table2" - not the most clear description - but this explains it.

Comment: I do think the sample result for 4 is incorrect, though - shouldn't it be 1?

Comment: Has to be 2 because that was before...

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 1):

Note: This answer makes assumptions about the provider/version of SQL that you are using.

```
DECLARE @temp table (idnode, idkey)

INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT 
   item.idnode, table2.idkey
FROM
    Table1 item
    inner join Table1 parent on item.idparent  = parent.idnode
    inner join Table2 on table2.idnode = parent.idnode;


SELECT * from @temp;
```

This should return the desired result, once you've checked that it is correct:

This next part assumes that you want to delete existing non-matching entries...

```
DELETE from table2;

insert into table2
select * from @temp;
```

to retain existing values:

```
insert into table2
select t.* from @temp t
left outer join table2 on table2.idnode = t.idnode
where table2.idnode is null
```

Comment: I dont know but is not working...its not returning me all the data.

Comment: Sorry, I misread and was cleaning up existing data... is the second option any better?

Comment: I think is better to get all the son from the parent that are on tabe2 and insert them on table2 with the same key the parent, delete the parent and delete the son exist on the table2 with different key. how could I do that?

Comment: Yeah, now I understand what you're trying to do - this method is a bit convoluted!

Comment: I edit and update and explain a little better, its making me crazy! I am Continue working on it hehehe!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use MERGE query in SQL Server 2008. You can find out details in below link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx